# create connected contour lines from set of points

Tags: python, vtk, pyvista

VTK and pyvista.

I am trying to implement from scratch (i.e., without using any library functions for contouring or interpolation ) an iso contour algorithm.

I am using pyvista to create a custom grid and render it.

With iso_contour function i am pushing (x, y, 0) points but i am not able to connect them to make an island of isocontour !!

I am here to ask help from you if you could help me achieve this using vtk or any other thing !

This is my code

```
import pyvista as pv 
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(10*x)+np.cos(4*y)-np.cos(3*x*y)

x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
y = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = f(XX, YY)

isovalue = 0.15

def iso_contour(array, target_value):
    contours = []
    rows, cols = array.shape
    
    # Loop through each cell in the array
    for i in range(rows-1):
        for j in range(cols-1):
            cell_verts = []
            
            # Check each corner of the cell
            for corner in [(i,j), (i+1,j), (i+1,j+1), (i,j+1)]:
                x, y = corner
                cell_verts.append((x, y, array[x,y]))


                # Check each edge of the cell
            for k in range(4):
                p1, p2 = cell_verts[k], cell_verts[(k+1)%4]
                if (p1[2] >= target_value) != (p2[2] >= target_value):
                    # Calculate intersection point
                    t = (target_value - p1[2]) / (p2[2] - p1[2])
                    x, y = p1[:2] + t * (np.array(p2[:2]) - np.array(p1[:2]))
                    contours.append((y, x, 0.0))
    
    return contours

contour_points = iso_contour(data, isovalue)
pl = pv.Plotter()
pl.add_mesh(grid, show_edges = True)
for i in range(len(contour_points)-1):
    line = pv.Line(contour_points[i], contour_points[i+1])
    pl.add_mesh(line, color='r', line_width=5)
pl.show()
```

I am expecting this as an output

[image]

but i am getting like this:

[image]
Is there any vtk filter or any thing that i can use or render in vtk that can give me that shape !

Thank you

Comment: The code cannot run as grid undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply loop along x (or y) axis and find the grid at your `target_value`. Because in that case the order of your `contour_points` is NOT along the contour line but along the axes. That's why you get messy lines.

Fortunately `pyvista` have provided `grid.contour` method to get contour line of surface stored in grid. So below code should do what you want.

```py
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(10*x)+np.cos(4*y)-np.cos(3*x*y)

x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
y = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = f(XX, YY)

isovalue = 0.15

pl = pv.Plotter(notebook=True)
grid = pv.UniformGrid(dimensions=(len(x), len(y), 1))
grid.point_data["values"] = data.flatten(order="F")
counter = grid.contour([isovalue])
pl.add_mesh(grid, show_edges = True)
pl.add_mesh(counter, color='red', line_width=5)

pl.show()
```

[image]

If you insist to write your own code to calculate contour lines, you cannot simple loop along axes, you need to check some [algorithms for contour](https://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html).

Comment: i can not use vontour function

Comment: @pravinpoudel what's the reason? the function fails? or you are prohibited to use that function. If the former pls add the traceback to your question(I can use it without problem.); if the latter you'll need to check the link I provided and write your own module using those algorithm.

Comment: No i am not allowed to !! this is a task given to be to be done from scratch for contour